# How do I analyze Simulink bus data in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, simulink

I want to do analysis of data from a Simulink bus in a C++ environment. I am aware of the existence of S-function blocks which I can use for that.

However, here comes the tricky part of the problem. The definition of the struct/Bus is simple but not fixed and to be defined by an external party.

For instance, it can be a combination

```
struct inp
{
    __int8 a;
    __int32 b;
};
```

but also 
    struct inp
    {
        __int8 a;
        __int32 b;
        __int64 o;
    };

My output will be an array of doubles based on a mathematical analysis which I will program in C/C++.
The S-function builder looks nice but you need to clearly define the bus (and thus the struct)
http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/slref/sfunctionbuilder.html

Any idea's for a solution? Is it possible to make a C++ S function that can generically handle multiple kind of buses (like both buses I mentioned)?

Comment: I had the same problem. Did you find a solution? Simulink needs the bus definition. Otherwise gives an error.